# PHP/MySQL Counting records for each user

Tags: php, mysql

So i'm trying to make a dive log that counts how many dives each user has specified by a number.

Like

### John

1# - First dive, 
2# - Second dive, 
3# - Third dive

### Mike

1# - First dive, 
2# - Second dive

```
 while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($card_query)) {
   $title = $rows["title"]; 

  echo '<li><strong>'.$number.'</strong>'.$title.'</li>';
}
```

How can I get the $number to specify #1, #2, #3 for that user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's well change all code (connection for security - and getvalue) like that:

```
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'user';
$pass = 'password';
$db = 'nameofdb';
$mysqli = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$db) or die($mysqli->error);
$query = "SELECT title FROM ??";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$number = 0;
while($rows = $result->fetch_array($card_query)) {
$title = $rows["title"]; 
echo '<li><strong>#'.$number.'</strong>'.$title.'</li>';
$number++;
}
```

Comment: You mean random?

Answer (score 0):

For example, by keeping track of rows as follows;

```
$number = 0;
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($card_query)) {
    $title = $rows["title"]; 
    $number++;
    echo '<li><strong>'.$number.'</strong>'.$title.'</li>';
}
```